# Literate PHP to test examples in README

Tags: php, phpunit, behat, literate-programming, parsedown

I'd like to include the examples from my README.md in my testsuite. So I can be sure that all examples still work and I don't need to write the same examples again as PHPUnit test cases.

Has anybody already written support for this?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a dirty hack. I get all code examples from the README with a regular expression and eval them in the testcase.

````
/**
 * @dataProvider parseReadme
 */
public function testReadme($example)
{
    $code = str_replace('HTMLBuilder', '\Comsolit\HTMLBuilder\HTMLBuilder', $example);
    eval($code);
}
public function parseReadme()
{
    $readme = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../README.md');
    $matches = [];
    preg_match_all('/(?:```PHP([^`]*)```)/ism', $readme, $matches);
    return array_map(
        function($x) {return [$x];},
        $matches[1]
    );
}
````

(from: [comsolit/html-builder](https://github.com/comsolit/html-builder/blob/master/tests/ReadmeTest.php))